# How do I find percentage difference from the first row and subsequent rows in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with certain values and I want to find the percentage difference from year 2020 for the subsequent time periods.

My dataframe is something like this:

```
Years          A              B          C           D          E
2020        801.566522  769.2986786 830.8725406 830.8725406 840.7192069
2021-2030   786.3122361 759.3832642 826.2453567 826.2453567 838.7446964
2031-2050   787.6490105 759.1486884 827.4489946 827.4489946 839.8352851
2041-2050   775.1016567 745.1193567 817.2389842 817.2389842 831.9880991
```

I need to calculate the percentage difference between the 2020 values and the values between subsequent decades, and the output should look something like this.

```
Years           A                 B               C                D            E
2021-2030   -0.019030593    -0.012888901    -0.005569066    -0.005569066    -0.002348597
2031-2050   -0.01736289     -0.013193823    -0.004120423    -0.004120423    -0.001051388
2041-2050   -0.03301643     -0.031430344    -0.016408722    -0.016408722    -0.010385284
```

I can do this in excel quite easily but since I have a large number of these files, I wanted to do it in python instead. I've tried using pct_change function but it calculates percentage difference between current and previous row, so not that useful in its base form. Can anyone help me out with a basic solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) with [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
In [877]: df.iloc[:, 1:] = (df.iloc[:, 1:] - df.iloc[0, 1:].values.squeeze()).div(df.iloc[:, 1:])

In [880]: df = df.loc[1:]

In [881]: df
Out[881]: 
       Years         A         B         C         D         E
1  2021-2030   -0.0194 -0.013057   -0.0056   -0.0056 -0.002354
2  2031-2050  -0.01767  -0.01337 -0.004137 -0.004137 -0.001052
3  2041-2050 -0.034144  -0.03245 -0.016682 -0.016682 -0.010494
```

Comment: I think I didn't phrase my question properly, because your solution is also calculating percentage difference between current row and previous row e.g. for 2031-2040, the percentage difference is being calculated from 2021-2030 values.

I wanted to calculate the percentage difference for each row starting from 2021-2030 from the 2020 values, so for example, for the 2031-2040 row, the percentage difference for all values will be calculated in regards to the 2020 values.

Comment: @HamzaWaheed Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly.

just one small question, in the first row, shouldn't it be .... div(df.iloc[0, 1:]) ? because this is the one that gave me the exact values

otherwise thank you so much

Comment: @MayankPorwal could you also give the answer for the % difference between current row and previous row?